# iOS app crashes/hangs when launched manually but not otherwise

Tags: ios, debugging, manual, launching-application

My app hangs at a certain point only when it is launched manually by tapping on the app icon on my device.  It runs fine when Xcode launches it on my device and when Xcode launches it on the simulator.

Any advice on debugging this situation? I've never had to debug an app that I launch manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xcode -> organizer -> Devices -> expand Your Testing Device -> Console

here you will see all logs (NSLog) from your app (among all other logs from the Device)
No Breakpoints etc. ofc